# Print output is correct but analysis says its wrong

Tags: python

Using the pre-loaded class *Person*

Using the Person class, write a function print_friend_info(person) which accepts a single argument, of type Person, and:

```
prints out their name
prints out their age
if the person has any friends, prints 'Friends with {name}'
```

Write a function create_fry() which returns a Person instance representing Fry. Fry is 25 and his full name is 'Philip J. Fry'

Write a function make_friends(person_one, person_two) which sets each argument as the friend of the other.

I have gotten the right output with what needs to be printed but when I try run the code through our code Analyzer it says this error:

"You need to print the name of the person's friend in print_friend_info"

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        """Construct a person object given their name, age and gender

        Parameters:
            name(str): The name of the person
            age(int): The age of the person
            gender(str): Either 'M' or 'F' for male or female

        """

        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._gender = gender
        self._friend = None

    def __eq__(self, person):
        return str(self) == str(person)

    def __str__(self):
        if self._gender == 'M':
            title = 'Mr'
        elif self._gender == 'F':
            title = 'Miss'
        else:
            title = 'Ms'

        return title + ' ' + self._name + ' ' + str(self._age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person: ' + str(self)

    def get_name(self):
        """
        (str) Return the name

        """
        return self._name

    def get_age(self):
        """
        (int) Return the age

        """
        return self._age

    def get_gender(self):
        """
        (str) Return the gender

        """
        return self._gender

    def set_friend(self, friend):
        self._friend = friend

    def get_friend(self):
        """
        (Person) Return the friend

        """
        return self._friend


def print_friend_info(person):
    person_name = person.get_name()
    person_age = person.get_age()
    person_gender = person.get_gender()
    person_friend = person.get_friend()

    print (person_name)
    print (person_age)

    if person_friend == None:

        return

    else:

        friendd = person_friend

        nameoffriend = friendd.get_name()

        print ('Friends with', nameoffriend)

    return


def create_fry():
    fry = Person("Philip J. Fry", 25, "M")
    return fry


def make_friends(person_one, person_two):
    made_friend1 = person_one.set_friend(person_two)
    made_friend2 = person_two.set_friend(person_one)
    return
```

--------- Test 1 ---------

Expected Output: Code Analyser

Test Result:

----- Analysis Errors -----

You need to print the name of the person's friend in print_friend_info

Input: bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40, 'M')

---

--------- Test 2 ---------

Expected Output: print_friend_info(bob)

Code Output: Bob Smith 40

Test Result: Correct!

---

Input: ed = Person('Ed', 8, 'M')

--------- Test 3 ---------

Expected Output: bob.set_friend(ed)

Code Output: Bob Smith 40 Friends with Ed

Test Result: Correct!

---

Input: fry = create_fry()

--------- Test 4 ---------

Expected Output: str(fry) -> 'Mr Philip J. Fry 25'

Test Result: Correct!

---

Input: leela = Person('T. Leela', 22, 'F')

--------- Test 5 ---------

Expected Output: make_friends(fry, leela)

Test Result: Correct!

Comment: What code analizer are you talking about?

Comment: Is this an assignment/homework?